# node.js JavaScript file changes do not take effect in frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix

There is a test and a production environment installed on a unix server. I got SSH and FTP access. I changed some *.js files in the test directory but the changes do not take effect in the frontend. Unfortunately I don't know so much about node.js and unix server but I now how to code JavaScript.

So here is my question: How can I "refresh" the test environment only (without affecting the productive environment and vice versa) so my changes take effect?

I searched many websites, read lots of articles and nodejs beginner guides but I don't know how to deal with this system who has been implemented by someone else I can't ask anymore.

Any help or hint will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT1: All local browser caches have been cleared (Chrome development console no cache active and console open - refresh)

EDIT2: JavaScript files are executed on the server as part of a node.js application

Comment: May be your changes cached?Try to set 'no-cache' checkbox in your browser console

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input, sorry, I forgot to mention: Yes, all local browser caches have been cleared (Chrome development console no cache active)

Comment: After you make changes to your .js files, you may need to restart the Node.js server in order for them to take affect. But as @Darth mentioned, your server may also be caching the response (not necessarily local browser cache).

Comment: There are too many unknown variables to provide a definite solution. To provide some guiding questions to find out more: Are you talking about JavaScript files that should be downloaded by the browser, or JavaScript files that should be executed on the server as part of a node.js application? If the former, how are the files served (what are you using as web server). How is the web server configured? Are there any proxy/caching servers between your computer and the server?

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help: I'm very sorry not to be able to supply you with more information on how this server is configured and set up. I feared that my question can't be answered on this little information. I thought that there might be some kind of "default" or "best pratice" installation for node.js. I alredy found out that there is a "forever" or "upstart" app who can do such things. Maybe I just have to investigate further and explore the installation deeper to hopefully find answers to this questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have stated that you are running server-side scripts, so try restarting Node.js. If you still have access to the terminal you are running from, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, but if you don't, run `pkill node` or `killall node` (depending on your system and preferences).

To automatically restart your server when a file changes in the future, use `nodemon`. To start using it, it is recommended to set up your command line in an npm script named `start`. To do this, add this to your `package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
}
```